# Rowwise maximum of multiple columns (ignoring null values)

Tags: sqlite, rsqlite

**How to apply the max()-functions to multiple columns, ignoring NULL values**

(in this context NULL is named NA).

**My data:**

```
# data 
df <- data.frame( a = sample(5), b = sample(5) ) 
df[2:3,1] <- NA
dbWriteTable(db1, "df", df, overwrite = TRUE )
```

**What I have tried**

[image]

**What I want:**

(notice that the column max1 does not contain NA)

[image]

I was hoping there was a simple way to do this in SQLite, but may there is not?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I need this in SQLite. I will remove the R-tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$max<-apply(X=df, MARGIN=1, FUN=max,na.rm=T)
```

Comment: You should explain why your code works. Just posting casual code is not how StackOverflow is supposed to work. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/333033) for example.

Comment: I do not think there is anyone who uses R and who does not know how the function `apply` works